# Shopify image slider- Always extend to users full screen

Tags: html, css, image, slider, shopify

right so,
i would really appreciate some help here. this code is well over my head
Basically the site is 976px;
the slider is fitting to this at most( if i extend the site size the slider stays at this 976px.)
anything under this it works well. (scales to mobile)

i want to increase the height it takes up and also i want to make it so it is width is always 100% of the users screen.

[image]

index page calling the slider

```
{% include 'slider' %}
```

slider.liquid

```
{% if settings.slider_home_enable %}
  <div class="flexslider" id="heroSlider" >
    <ul class="slides">
      {% for i in (1..6) %}
        {% capture slide %}slide_{{ i }}{% endcapture %}
        {% capture slide_link %}slide_{{ i }}_link{% endcapture %}
        {% capture slide_img %}slide_{{ i }}.jpg{% endcapture %}
        {% capture slide_img_alt %}slide_{{ i }}_alt{% endcapture %}
        {% capture slide_img_caption %}slide_{{ i }}_caption{% endcapture %}
        {% if settings[slide] %}
          <li>
            <a href="{{ settings[slide_link] }}" class="slide-link">
              <img src="{{ slide_img | asset_url }}" alt="{{ settings[slide_img_alt] }}">
              {% unless settings[slide_img_caption] == blank %}
              <p class="h3 flex-caption small--hide">{{ settings[slide_img_caption] }}</p>
              {% endunless %}
            </a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

stylesheet

```
/*============================================================================
  #FlexSlider
    - jQuery FlexSlider v2.2.0 | http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/
    - Contributing author: Tyler Smith (@mbmufffin)
==============================================================================*/
.flexslider {
  margin: 0 0 $gutter;
  padding: 0;
}
.flexslider li { margin: 0; }
.flexslider .slides > li {
  display: none; /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  @include backface();
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.slides { @include clearfix; }
html[xmlns] .slides { display: block; }
* html .slides { height: 1%; }

/*================ No JS Fallback ================*/
.no-js .slides > li:first-child { display: block; }
.flexslider { position: relative; zoom: 1; }
.flex-viewport {max-height: 2000px; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; -moz-transition: all 1s ease; -o-transition: all 1s ease; transition: all 1s ease; }
.loading .flex-viewport { max-height: 300px; }
.flexslider .slides { zoom: 1; }
.carousel li { margin-right: 5px; }





/*================ Direction Nav ================*/
.flex-direction-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.flex-direction-nav { *height: 0; }
.flex-direction-nav a  {
  display: block;
  width: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  @include transition(all .3s ease);
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {
  opacity: 0!important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: default;
}

.flex-direction-nav a {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: {
    color: transparent;
    repeat: no-repeat;
    size: 20px auto;
  }

  /*================ Hide SVG arrows in oldIE ================*/
  .lte-ie9 & {
    display: none;
  }

  &.flex-prev {
    background-image: url("data:image.....");
    background-position: center left;
  }

  &.flex-next {
    background-image: url("data:image...");
    background-position: center right;
  }
}

/*================ Control Nav ================*/
.flex-control-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -$gutter;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;

  li {
    margin: 0 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}

.flex-control-paging li a {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ededed;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;

  &:hover {
    background-color: #333;
  }

  &.flex-active {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: $colorPrimary;
    cursor: default;
  }
}

.flex-control-thumbs {margin: 5px 0 0; position: static; overflow: hidden;}
.flex-control-thumbs li {width: 25%; float: left; margin: 0;}
.flex-control-thumbs img {width: 100%; display: block; opacity: .7; cursor: pointer;}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {opacity: 1;}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {opacity: 1; cursor: default;}

@include at-query ($max, $medium) {
  .flex-direction-nav a {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 25px;
  }
  .flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev {
    left: 0;
    background-position: center right;
  }
  .flex-direction-nav a.flex-next {
    right: 0;
    background-position: center left;
  }
}

@include at-query ($min, $large) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev { left: 10px; }
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next { right: 10px; }
  .flexslider:hover .flex-prev { opacity: 1; left: (-$gutter)+5; }
  .flexslider:hover .flex-next { opacity: 1; right: (-$gutter)+5; }
}

@include at-query ($min, $maxWidthBp) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev { left: 20px; }
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next { right: 20px; }
  .flexslider:hover .flex-prev { opacity: 1; left: -45px; }
  .flexslider:hover .flex-next { opacity: 1; right: -45px; }
}

/*================ Captions ================*/
.flex-caption {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  padding: $gutter/2;
}

/*================ Custom Flexslider Styles ================*/
.flexslider .slides {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slide-link {
  position: relative;
  display: block;

  img {
    display: block;
  }
}

#heroSlider {
  padding-bottom: $gutter*2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $colorBorder;


  .flex-control-nav {
    bottom: 40px;
  }

  .flex-direction-nav a {
    bottom: $gutter*2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please setup a demo of the code so we can test it and provide solution. Maybe here or JSfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I literally just did this on the Retina theme to create a short looping video background.  I needed it to stretch the entire width and it was being constrained by one of the parent elements.   It doesn't look like you have the same theme but the concept is the same.

You need to use dev tools and inspect the elments to find out which element on the page is constricting it from going 100%.   You then need to move your slider element outside that element.   Then it's as simple as just setting the CSS, making margins/padding to 0 etc...

Let me know if you have any questions and I can help you further.   If you post a link to the site, I can look at it for you and tell you what needs to be done.

Comment: Yeah , I realise that it was my only way (before i saw this) what i ended up doing was to place this in the theme page, outside the wrapper and then

  {% if template == 'index' %}
  {% include 'slider' %}
  {%endif%}

then done the css

The problem was this was being called in the index file , so i couldnt get out of the page container

Comment: tbh i think that's what i had to end up doing too.  Forgot about that part.  Glad you got it worked out.