# Html Simple Image slider

Tags: html, css, image, slider

I want a image slider for shopify. However The full page(which takes up about 50% of the page(centered))  is in a wrapper. This contains the footer and header. Each contents page is then inside  a container. And then the contents of the page is there.

I want to make this image slider be 100% of the screen. Whatever that screen size is.

Can somebody please tell me about how to do this, In particular how to add in any java script and jquery as i am partially bad on this

Thanks.

Comment: i was trying to use flexslider , but for the life of me i couldnt get it working, It keep refusing to work.- i tried asking this yesterday to get flexslider working but no luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226302/shopify-image-slider-always-extend-to-users-full-screen

so i want to start from scratch

Comment: Have you tried adding the CSS `width:100% !important;` to the slider div?

Comment: yes,  but i have had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

is this something you could use?
It's a library for using effects on most elements.
I'm using it myself on my own website for an automatic slider between divs.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: No , im not looking for effects. Seems too complicated for what i want

Comment: Oh okay ;) I assumed this was what you were searching for.

Comment: no , thanks for the reply though. I just want a simple slider but it has to be 100% width of the screen